# If $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_{2n}=L$ does that mean that $\lim _{n\to \infty }a_{n}=L$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am a new user in math exchange and currently starting my undergraduate study in mathematics.

I tried to proof the above statement using the definition of limits at infinity as follow.
Suppose $\lim _{n\to  \infty }a_{2n}=L$.

Then by definition,

> $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N s.t.$ if $n>N$ then, $|a_{2n}-L|<\epsilon$

If that is the case then,

$$2n>N$$

Let $B=2n$. Hence,

$$b>N$$

Substituting $2n$ using $b$, we get that
$$|a_{b}-L|<\epsilon$$

Then we have proved that  $\lim _{b\to  \infty }a_{b}=L$ which can be rewritten as $\lim _{n\to  \infty }a_{n}=L$.

**However**, a counter example for this proof is when $a_n=(-1)^n$. For even $n$, the term will always equal to one, which means that
$$\lim _{n\to  \infty }(-1)^{2n}=1$$

But,
$$\lim _{n\to  \infty }(-1)^{n}=DNE$$

Since the value will oscillate between -1 and 1.

So it seems that $\lim _{n\to  \infty }a_{2n}=L$ does not imply that $\lim _{n\to  \infty }a_{n}=L$.

So my question is, which part of my proof is wrong? I am really confused as I think that the above substitution using $b=2n$ used in my proof is allowed.

Comment: With $b=2n,$ $|a_{b}-L|<\epsilon$ is guaranteed not for every integer $b>N$ but only for the even $b$'s.

Comment: The proof fails in beginning. There is an $\epsilon = 0.5$ for which the limit definition fails.

Comment: @AnneBauval Okay, now I got the point where my proof is wrong. Thank you very much!

Comment: @openspace but if the term is a multiple of 2 ($a_{2n}$), wouldn't it mean that $|a_{2n}-L|=0<\epsilon=0.5$ for all n?

Comment: Yeah, indexes have nothing really to do with the values of the terms.  Just the point were the terms reach a degree of converges. As your indexing is restricted to even numbers any manipulation you do you will still be restricted to even numbers.  If we use $b=2n$ for index notice we now of terms indexed by multiples of $0.5$.  If we say $N=50$ then then we have $a_{106} = a_{2n;n=53}=a_{b;b=106}$ but we also have $a_{107}=a_{b;b=106}$ but $a_{107}\ne = a_{2n}$ for any $n$.... BTW, I don't understand openspace's comment and think they may have misunderstood your post.

Comment: It might (or might not) be worth noting that $\lim a_n =L\implies \lim a_{2n} = L$. but the implication is not bidirectional.

Comment: @fleablood Ahh i see, got the idea. thank you for the help!!